# Method in Java Box class

Tags: java

I created a class by named Box which having instance variables and other class name Boxdemo in which i uses main()..Here raises my doubt..while i executed through javac,i executed like **javac Boxdemo.java**,it shows two class files of **Box** and **Boxdemo**..Why it creates two class files without using the main function in Box class.Is it possible to run both the class files,as i executed **javac** ****Box.java****,it shows error **javac:file not found**

```
class Box {
    double width;
    double height;
    double depth;

    void volume() {
        System.out.print("volume is");
        System.out.println(width * height * depth);
    }
}

class Boxdemo
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Box mybox1 = new Box();
        Box mybox2 = new Box();
        mybox1.width = 10;
        mybox1.height = 20;
        mybox1.depth = 15;
        mybox2.width = 13;
        mybox2.height = 25;
        mybox2.depth = 17;
        mybox1.volume();
        mybox2.volume();
    }
}
```

Comment: studying herbert schild :)

Comment: Yes,i am new to this java

Comment: Is javac saying 'file not found' or is your OS saying it can't find javac? It's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should have two separate source files, each containing only one class.

You then compile the main class with javac and it will automatically compile all the needed classes.

Finally, you execute the class that contains the main method.

This is what you should have, I took the liberty of improving your code in the process:

Box.java

```
public class Box
{
    public double width; // You should use private attributes, a constructor, getters and setters.
    public double height;
    public double depth;

    public void volume()
    {
        System.out.println("volume is " + width*height*depth);
    }
```

Boxdemo.java

```
public class Boxdemo
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Box mybox1=new Box();
        Box mybox2=new Box();
        mybox1.width=10;
        mybox1.height=20;
        mybox1.depth=15;
        mybox2.width=13;
        mybox2.height=25;
        mybox2.depth=17;
        mybox1.volume();
        mybox2.volume();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have several classes in the same file, but only one can be public.

Comment: Yes, seeing that there is no public/private modifier, I guess it's not the problem here, OP must be new to Java.

Answer (score 0):

Compilation will create a .class file for each class contained in your file: one for Box and and another one for BoxDemo. Anyway, the one with main method must be `public` and the name of the file should be this class name with .java extension (in your case, Boxdemo.java). Then you'll be able to compile this file.

Answer (score 0):

.class files will be created for each class in the package on compiling with javac compiler....
Though you have compiled Boxdemo.java... it is implicitly using the Box class so both will be complied and .class files will be generated

Comment: Is it possible to run both the class files by adding the main function in Box class

Comment: not.. because in java you can have n number of classes in a single file.. however, only one class with mian() method in it...that class will be used as a startup class for the program...

Comment: No we can have two classes with main method in same file.But one thing both should not be marked as public and name the source file with anyName.

Comment: i will try without mentioning public in one class

Comment: @Algorithmist - what i mean to say is also same... if the class is not public.. it will not be accessible for java interpreter... hence you would not be able to run it...

Comment: Thank you pavan,Algorithmist

Comment: Refer this http://ideone.com/yOUZaj and now you can run it using either java Class1 or java Class2

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

**All classes in Java have to be compiled into separate files.** Hence, when you used javac, two files were created and not one - as you would have anticipated. **That's because `Boxdemo` is your driver class - which calls and instantiates the methods of the `Box` class.**

Second, when you compile programs with javac, it creates a `.class` file for every Java class. So, in your case, you correctly see two `.class` files - which would be: `Box.class` and `Boxdemo.class`.

And, to run to a compiled java program you call `java` on the compiled program (without using the class extension). That is:

```
java Boxdemo
```

Again, note there is no `.class` extension in the executed command.

Of course, if you're using an IDE, this entire process is taken care of for you - and may involve Makefiles and the like. However, this is generally what goes on in the background.